# What is the difference between push and give a push?

Tags: phrase-usage, light-verbs

I would like to know the difference between push and give a push when used in the conversation.
Why people use the phrase, 'give a push' instead of the word, 'push'? 
ex) walk=take a walk, shower=take a shower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're interchangeable when used for a single short-term event

> I pushed him
>   I gave him a push
>
> I pushed him off a cliff
>   I gave him a push off a cliff
>
> I pushed the car
>   I gave the car a push

If something is pushed for a long period, however,

> I pushed the car home

is preferable because

> I gave the car a push home

might imply that you gave it one push and the momentum impelled it all the way home (fine, of course, if that's what actually happened).

Answer (score 3):

"Give a push" is used when you *want* someone to push you. "Give" implies that you are asking for the push.

"He pushed me" implies that I did not asked to be pushed. "He gave me a push" means that I asked to be pushed, and he did so.

Comment: Good explanation, however it is probably applicable only when the object being pushed is the speaker. However, what about the difference between "Give it a push" and "Push it" as a response to "The door is stuck"?

Comment: @Phylyp - no difference in that case. It would have been more complete for me to explain that "Give it a push" is colloquial/informal. "Push the door" - a standard imperative sentence - is not incorrect in any of these cases.